# How can I add badges for drawer menu items in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to add badges (showing that new content is available) to Drawer in Flutter.
I use ListTile to present menu items inside Drawer widget.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
ListTile(
  title: Text("I'm a list tile"),
  // this trailing widget can be the badge.
  trailing: Container(
    height: 14,
    width: 14,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.red,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100)),
    ),
  ),
)
```

[image]